# Javascript game loop state in an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, scope, html5-canvas, anonymous-function

I'm messing around with canvas, and starting by reading a bunch of game loop snippets/posts and combining them into the best one possible.

I came upon this snippet today (it's part way through [a post](http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/index.html), so they make further iterations on it later. But I'm integrating the ideas as I go), but it's perplexing me a little.

```
Game.run = (
    function() {
        var loops = 0;
        var skipTicks = 1000 / Game.fps;
        var maxFrameSkip = 10;
        var nextGameTick = (new Date).getTime();

        return function {
            loops = 0;

            while ((new Date).getTime() > nextGameTick && loops < maxFrameSkip) {
                Game.update();
                nextGameTick += skipTicks;
                loops++;
            }

            Game.draw();
        };
    }
)();

Game._intervalId = setInterval(Game.run, 1000 / Game.fps);
```

So `Game.run` gets assigned the result of the outer function, which is the inside function. But the inside function relies on `nextGameTick`, which is defined in the outer function...

So will this game be keeping its state in the outer anonymous function? If so, any ideas why they did that?

And as for e.g. `loops`, which is set to 0 every call, is it declared outside to avoid re-declaring the variable again each time?

Comment: That while loop is going to make your game choppy.

Comment: @Shmiddty: Yes, I imagine it will. As I mentioned though, this is the unfinished loop from partway through [the tutorial](http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/index.html). I don't think any of this code will end up in the final version. Out of curiosity though, I assume you say it will be choppy because the multiple update calls are run in a single while loop without going back to the UI between them? Is that the reason, or do you have another?

Comment: basically, yes. But less about update being called, and more that it's not releasing control to the UI until the while loop is done. I'm not even sure the code is releasing control to the UI at all since I see no timeout, interval, or requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I'm missing the following line, which actually makes use of the Game.run method: `Game._intervalId = setInterval(Game.run, 1000 / Game.fps);`
I'll edit the question for posterity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will.

The `local frame` of the function you returned is inside the `local frame` of the Game.run function.  Therefore, any variable that gets changed in Game.run around the function you return is persistent.  The parent frame of that function will look inside of Game.run any time you try to reference your nextTick variable.

Answer (score 2):

This type of construction is called an *immediately invoked function expression* or *IIFE*.

This pattern is used to manage scope. In this case, we are preventing variables like `loops` and `skipTicks` from leaking into the global scope. More importantly, they are caught in the closure of the inner function, and thus persist across calls to that inner function. By using an IIFE, only our inner function can see this state, and it is hidden from the global context.

Here's a [decent article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) on the pattern. See in particular the section on saving state with closures.